# Beyond the Sword just run into a black screen, how can I fix it?

Tags: wine, games, playonlinux

I have problem on my Ubuntu 12.04 with Civilization IV:BtS. I installed Civilization IV: complete using playonlinux. Civ4 and DLC Warlords work out of box, but latest DLC does not. When I run it, black screen appears, I hear music theme, and I see the cursor. Game doesn't crash.

On Arch Linux the game runs well with the same configuration and the same version of wine. Any ideas? May it be caused by hybrid graphic cards on my laptop? I have latest drivers installed

Answer (score 1):

According to [this report](http://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=version&iId=10158&iTestingId=80314) you should make some actions before Civilization IV:BsT work as appropriate.

### Prerequisites

- You must have installed winetricks package:

  ```
  sudo apt-get install winetricks
  ```
- You should have this native files `msvcr71`, `msxml3`, `msxml3r.dll`, `mscoree.dll`, `streamci.dll`, `ddrawex.dll`
- Disable gameux
- Install the patchs [1](http://www.firaxis.com/games/game_detail.php?gameid=16&showcon=2) [2](http://www.firaxis.com/games/game_detail.php?gameid=6&showcon=2) and [3](http://www.firaxis.com/games/game_detail.php?gameid=13&showcon=2)

### Starting

You should run winetricks to install DirectX and other Windows libraries and fonts:

```
winetricks d3dx9* msxml3 msxml4 vcrun2003 quartz devenum corefonts lucida tahoma
```

Once you do so, you should be able to play the game.

**Remember:** it wasn't tested a full game until the end, nor all eras, nor the multiplayer function. Also, the version tested was *Civilization IV plus WARLORDS and BEYOND THE SWORD expansion packs*.

Comment: I've already tried this solution and result was the same: Civ4 and Warlords run out of box, Beyond the Sword -> blackscreen.

Comment: @Radek well... I didn't say that was a 100% sure solution. Wine change everyday and while "fixing" something they break some other, so the best thing is wait and see...

Comment: Make sure you are adding the necessary libraries and fonts to the version of wine that your PoL is using.  And try running the game in windowed mode (or fullscreen if it is windowed mode that is not working.)

Comment: how to "Disable gameux"?

Comment: @Fabiotk according to the latest report on WineHQ, in winecfg you will find that configuration. Check the howto in the same page https://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=version&iId=10158#notes Also, that recommendation is for version 1.4. Try 2.3 without changing a thing (only installing the patches).